# Обработка SQL запроса в цикле (хранимая процедура)

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть выборка:

```
SELECT issues.id, issues.priority_id, issues.project_id, issues.subject,  
c.value, t.tag_id from issues 
INNER JOIN taggings t ON issues.id = t.taggable_id and t.tag_id = 623
INNER JOIN custom_values c ON c.customized_id = issues.id and 
c.custom_field_id = 105
WHERE issues.priority_id = 4 and issues.project_id = 66 and issues.status_id    
NOT IN ( 5, 6, 11, 9) ORDER BY issues.id
```

В результате выводятся такие данные:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать так, чтобы каждой записи в этой выборке в поле value подставилось число, по порядку от 1 до кол-ва строк в выборке? Т.е. например, первая запись с id = 59517 в поле value получает значение 1, вторая запись с id = 72821 в поле value получает значение 2, и т.д., те по возрастанию id, соответственно нумеруется поле value по порядку от 1 до 31 (как в данном случае).

Comment: Число надо подстваить только врезультат при выборке? Или же и в базе надо его обновить?

Comment: @newman в базе обновить

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так вам выборка нужна или обновить значение в таблице custom_value(UPDATE)?
Если просто выборка, то пронумеровать можно так:

```
  SELECT issues.id, issues.priority_id, issues.project_id, 
    issues.subject, @I := @I+1 as value, t.tag_id 
  from issues 
    INNER JOIN taggings t ON issues.id = t.taggable_id and t.tag_id = 623
    INNER JOIN custom_values c ON c.customized_id = issues.id and 
      c.custom_field_id = 105 
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @I := 0)I
  WHERE issues.priority_id = 4 and issues.project_id = 66 
    and issues.status_id NOT IN ( 5, 6, 11, 9) 
  ORDER BY issues.id
```

Если нужно обновить значение, то например так:

```
UPDATE custom_values
  INNER JOIN issues ON custom_values.customized_id = issues.id and custom_values.custom_field_id = 105
  INNER JOIN taggings t ON issues.id = t.taggable_id and t.tag_id = 623
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @I := 0)I
SET Value = @I := @I + 1 
WHERE issues.priority_id = 4 and issues.project_id = 66 
  and issues.status_id NOT IN ( 5, 6, 11, 9)
ORDER BY issues.id
```

Вроде так должно быть правильно. Но вы можете прочесть подробнее о синтаксисе [UPDATE + JOIN в MySQL тут](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-update-join/)

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы обновить значения в БД, обойдите все строки выборки с помощью [Cursor](https://habrahabr.ru/post/46333/). Создайте некоторую переменную @value, которая будет увеличиваться на 1 с каждой новой строкой. Для каждой строки, полученной с помощью FETCH, установите значение @value в необходимое поле записи БД, имеющей полученное из строки выборки значение issues.id.